# 64Bit ubuntu and 32Bit apps

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, aptitude, binary

I am trying to run a 32bit server process on my VPS, however when I do so it is having problems loading the shared libraries the process needs.

When googling around they suggest "sudo apt-get install ia32-libs", when I do this I fear Ubuntu wants to replace every single package I have installed with 32bit ones, all kinds of packages previously installed ( including nginx and php ) are asked to be installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you paste the output of what it is trying to install? (ctrl-c to cancel etc...)

Comment: Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
WARNING: untrusted versions of the following packages will be installed!
  php5-xsl libmagickcore3 mysql-server php5 libmagickwand3 php5-sqlite 
  libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server-core-5.5 php5-snmp php5-gd 
  libmysqlclient18 php5-imagick php-pear php5-curl php5-pspell php5-suhosin 
  php5-xmlrpc mysql-client php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-memcache php5-cgi 
  php5-cli php5-dev php5-fpm mysql-common php5-common mysql-server-5.5 
  mysql-client-5.5 -- I am starting to get the feeling that it simply is installing 32bit for EVERY library on the system..

Comment: "/home/jabwd/etserver/etmain/qagame.mp.i386.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
Sys_LoadDll(qagame) failed dlopen() completely!

Comment: What repository have you added to your sources.list?  Those shouldn't be showing as untrusted.

Comment: deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable all
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org/ stable all


I added these 3 extra ones a few weeks ago, I think it was because I had to update some package that wasn't yet available on the ubuntu repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What am I doing wrong?"
Well, it looks like you have mixed up a Ubuntu installation with lots of third party (Dotdeb / debian) packages and ended up in DEB-hell.
Sidenote: *The packages from Dotdeb should work on Ubuntu, but no additional support will be provided.*

Anyway, installation of `ia32-libs` on Ubuntu *should* look somewhat like this, when used with the `no-install-recommends` switch enabled:

```
# apt-get install --no-install-recommends ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc6-i386 libv4l-0
Suggested packages:
  lib32asound2-plugins
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ia32-libs lib32asound2 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc6-i386 libv4l-0
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.7MB of archives.
After this operation, 173MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Only 10 new packages needed on my Ubuntu 10.04.4 amd64 here.

From my point of view a clean installation of your "Enemy Territory" Ubuntu-server is the safest way to go. De-installing the dotdeb packages (PHP and MySQL-packages) and start from scratch with different, **official** repositories is another way.
Or install Debian on the VPS and use the Dotdeb-repository.